# Can I sort songs by Apple ID?

Tags: sort

I have about 300 songs that were purchased with my ex-wifes account.  I can't play them because they have a different Apple ID and were purchased by her account.  Does anyone know how to "sort" for those songs so I can deleter them?

Answer (score 1):

[Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/) contains a script that should be useful for you. The [Track Down Purchases](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=trackdownpurchases) script can sort your purchases into playlists separated by account name, which should make it easy for you to find and subsequently delete songs not on your account.